# Authorization in R API, specifically for League of Legends

Tags: r, api

I am learning how to use API in R and it is going well for the most part, but I am having trouble getting any data from the league of legends API.

For reference, I used this article as a start (https://www.dataquest.io/blog/r-api-tutorial/) and cop

```
res <- GET("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
res
```

This worked just fine and has a 200 status, but I am not interested in that data.

What I want is data about league of legends, so I am trying to use:

```
base.url <- "https://na1.api.riotgames.com"
path <- "/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/"

API_Key <- read.table("riotkey.txt")
API_KEY <- API_Key$V1

Summoner_ID <- read.table("summonerID.txt")
SUMMONER_ID <- Summoner_ID$V1

path <- paste0(path,SUMMONER_ID)

LoL_API_Test <- GET(base.url, path = path,
                    add_headers(Authorization = API_KEY))
LoL_API_Test
```

This is Riot's explanation for the 403 error - Forbidden. "This error indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. There is no distinction made between an invalid path or invalid authorization credentials (e.g., an API key)"

I am certain that my API key and summoner ID are correct.
So I assume the issue has to be with how I am requesting the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MrFlick I tried that, but it still gave me a 403 error.

Comment: @MrFlick my API key expired last night, so once I updated it the change to "X-Riot-Token" was the solution actually. tyvm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular API expects the API key to be passed in a header called "X-Riot-Token", not "Authorization". Change your call to

```
LoL_API_Test <- GET(base.url, path = path,
                    add_headers("X-Riot-Token" = API_KEY))
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you know when you are calling the API what the key needs to be passed as?